# Display array of documents as objects with id as key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to use `project` or `group` in mongo to convert an array of documents or subdocuments into an object with documents ObjectId as key and document/subdocument as value?

For example:

```
const book = Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    authors: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author'}]
})

const author = Schema({name: {type: String}})
```

If you query for all books:

`Book.find({}).populate('authors').lean().exec()`

then you get:

```
[{
    id: 10,
    name: 'Book 1',
    authors: [{
        id: 1, 
        name: 'Author1'
    }]

},...]
```

but I would like to have this:

```
[{
    id: 10,    
    name: 'Book 1',
    authors: {
        1: {id: 1, name: 'Author 1'}
    }
},...]
```

I know that iterating over the objects after querying from mongo will do it but I guess that running the query at mongo is more efficient.

Comment: Are looking for something like this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/#exp._S_arrayToObject ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main consideration here is that the "keys" you want are actually `ObjectId` values as defined in your schema and not really a "string", which is actually a requirement for a JavaScript Object since all "keys" **must** be a "string". For JavaScript this really is not much of an issue since JavScript will "stringify" any argument specified as a "key", but it **does matter** for BSON, which is what MongoDB actually *"speaks"*

So you can do this with MongoDB, but you need MongoDB 4.x at least in order to support the [`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) aggregation operator or it's *shortcut* method [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/). This also means that rather than `populate()`, you actually use MongoDB [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/):

```
let results = await Books.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Author.collection.name,
    "localField": "authors",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "authors"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "authors": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
         "$map": {
           "input": "$authors",
           "in": { "k": { "$toString": "$$this._id" }, "v": "$$this" }
         }
       }
     }
  }}
])
```

Or if you prefer the alternate syntax:

```
let results = await Books.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "authors",
    "let": { "authors": "$authors" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$authors" ] } } },
      { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "k": { "$toString": "$_id" },
        "v": "$$ROOT"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "authors"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "authors": { "$arrayToObject": "$authors" }
  }}
])
```

Which would return something like:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7f046a7cefb8bff9304af8"),
        "name" : "Book 1",
        "authors" : {
                "5c7f042e7cefb8bff9304af7" : {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7f042e7cefb8bff9304af7"),
                        "name" : "Author 1"
                }
        }
}
```

So the [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) does the actual "Object" output where you supply it an array of objects with `k` and `v` properties corresponding to *key* and *value*. But it **must** have a valid "string" in `"k"` which is why you [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) over the array content to reformat it first.

Or as the *alternate*, you can [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) within the `pipeline` argument of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) instead of using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) later for exactly the same thing.

With *client side* JavaScript, the translation is a similar process:

```
let results = await Books.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Author.collection.name,
    "localField": "authors",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "authors"
  }},
  /*
  { "$addFields": {
    "authors": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
         "$map": {
           "input": "$authors",
           "in": { "k": { "$toString": "$$this._id" }, "v": "$$this" }
         }
       }
     }
  }}
  */
])

results = results.map(({ authors, ...rest }) => 
  ({
    ...rest, 
    "authors": d.authors.reduce((o,e) => ({ ...o, [e._id.valueOf()]: e }),{})
  })
 )
```

Or with `populate()`

```
let results = await Book.find({}).populate("authors");
results = results.map(({ authors, ...rest }) => 
  ({
    ...rest, 
    "authors": (!authors) ? {} : authors.reduce((o,e) => ({ ...o, [e._id.toString()]: e }),{})
  })
 )
```

**NOTE** however that `populate()` and `$lookup` are really quite different. MongoDB [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is a *single request* to the server that returns *one response*. Using `populate()` actually invokes *multiple queries* and does the "joining" in *client side JavaScript code* even if it hides what it is doing from you.

Comment: Neil, you are like a secret ninja taking care for us mere mortals!

Comment: @DiegoGallegos There's nothing happening that would cause a problem here if empty i.e `[]`. If there is *"no property at all"* for `authors` then you would need `$ifNull` i.e `let: { authors: { $ifNull: [ "$authors", [] ] } }` or the same in an intitial `$project` for the legacy form. Same sort of thing applies for JavaScript array properties as well. `(!authors) ?  {} : authors.reduce(...`